# Simple query to database - condition comes from csv

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv

I have been wondering one thing. Could it be possible to query database so that "where" clause condition is given in csv file?

Like let's say that I have database and in there table (name some_table) like this:

```
id         company_id   created_at
0001c73d   12345        2016-1-1
rewrewrf   45678        2016-2-1
0001c73d   57986        2016-3-1
vcxcv34d   21346        2016-4-1
23215fsf   47896        2016-6-1
```

And my some.csv would look like this:

```
error_id;company_id 
32rgfvx4;12345     
fds44322;45678     
fdsf46hh;57986    
989jh2f4;21346   
f43452fg;47896
```

So the query could be something like:

```
select company_id, created_at
from some_table
where company_id IN ('some.csv:column2')
```

Get the idea?

Could this be done with python or like straight with some SQL program (addon/script..) or something? Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure this can be done through PowerShell

Comment: SQL Server has `OPENROWSET` which I think can be used for something like this, but I don't believe that MySQL has an equivalent. As @dfundako points out, Powershell can do it (depending on the size of the CSV and your approach). I would think that Python could as well.

Comment: You can load the CSV file into a temporary table and use that table for filtering. But why don't you just parse the CSV file with python?

Comment: Dont know much about Powershell and total newbie with Python too. But shouldn't be that hard, thanks for the tips. Going to investigate more.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL solution with [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html):**

Create a temporary table matching the CSV data:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_errors (
    error_id   VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    company_id VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX company_id (company_id)
);
```

Load your data into a temporary table:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/full/path/to/csv/errors.csv'
INTO TABLE tmp_errors
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Use the temporary table to filter your select:

```sql
select company_id, created_at
from some_table
where company_id IN (select company_id from tmp_errors);
```

Or

```sql
select t.company_id, t.created_at, e.error_id
from some_table t
join tmp_errors e using(company_id);
```

Comment: Hmm.. so I could put this all in python script and run it?

Comment: I have no clue of python :-) This is a pure MySQL solution. You can execute that queries from mysql-console, a tool like HeidiSQL and Workbench or from a webinterface like PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Yep I know that got Sequel Pro at this moment. Hmm I could try to run this through python. Also got one friend who knows about Ruby and he said this should be peanuts. If we just get the SSL tunnel to work.

Comment: This would work if one has writing rights to the database but since I have only rights to read, this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Taapsa, you only need the [CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-temporary-tables).